# Best practice for interactive maps on mobile?

Tags: interaction-design, lean-ux

We're building this - http://splasshdata.meteor.com/

On larger, non-mobile screens - its a better experience than it is on mobile.

We want a "mobile web" experience, but find that it's doubling our work to consider both.

I've heard about think mobile first, but we missed that boat in trying to put together an alpha. So my question to all the experts on usability out there is twofold -

1) Does the map work as the first thing end users see on both mobile and web? Will they know what to do, after all it's a map with not much options anywhere else?

2) If yes, would either a bootstrap well, modal, or help icon nearby help to provide feedback on what users are suppose to do if it's the first thing they see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to do some sort of interstitial for first time users to explain what they need to do? Whether a model or a parallax type layout would work very well.  Just make sure you remember whether users have seen it so you don't annoy them with the same welcome screen each time.

As for the mobile first experience though, there is a lot of work that has to be done on that front. Here is why:

- The icons could be bigger. The point of mobile first is to make the text and the buttons big so that it can easily be used on mobile.
- Rather than a box that says "click and mouseover" change that to "selected location" only. On mobile you will only see where the user taps.
- Show an indicator where the user taps. Unlike having a mouse where I can see the mouse, I have no idea where I am tapping.
- After the user taps somewhere provide options for them to add something at that location rather than having an extra step for adding something at that point.
- Make sure you can tell the difference between a tap, pinching and a swiping motion. All are very distinct. Only trigger the add on the tap.

If you put some details about what they are doing and let them right in by employing the simple steps for them to start using your app it will work significantly better. As it stands I would have likely dropped out as a user by going to your home page. Navigating to the url you provide on my phone gave me no indicator that I should be going to the map.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Ok, We'll focus on your bullet this and comment when it's done to show off the recommendations! Thanks again!